# Getting an "Unsupported media type-415" on an ajax call- Jquery,ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm calling an ajax function to update a certain record and I'm getting a 415-Unsupported Media type. Below is the js:

```
$("#update").on("click", function(){
    event.preventDefault();
        return $.ajax('/update/record',{
            method: 'PUT',
            data:{
                date: date
            },
           success: function(){
              alert("record updated successfully");
           }

        });
```

html:

```
<form>
    <button type="submit" id="update-cc">Update</button>
</form>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here or what I need to add to get the correct form of the ajax call.Any ideas????

Thanks!

Comment: Is that what the server is saying on the response?

Comment: What server are you on apache, tomcat, IIS??

Comment: You get 415 Unsupported Media type, when your method(PUT), is not the one which is configured(say GET/POST)

Comment: Posting the serverside code that returns that status would probably be more interesting than the ajax code ?

Comment: @Jack: yes the server throws 415

Comment: @Durgesh: using apache server

Comment: @DurgeshChaudhary:ok, so i want to use the ajax call for updating my record, what would be the best way?

Comment: change ` method: 'PUT' ` to ` method: 'POST' `, it should go through

Comment: unfortunately, didnt work: now says: 405-Method not allowed

Comment: The problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to set the contentType and dataType in your ajax request

```
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "json",
```